# Changes to Eloquent model+migration not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm adding some authentication to my Laravel 5.4 project. However, when updating the provided User.php file's (which is an Eloquent model) $fillable array to correspond to my new Users table migration, the insert query upon registering a new user doesn't propagate the changes. See below.

```
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'api_token' => str_random(60),
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
        ]);
    }
```

I've added 'api-token' to my database, and updated my model's $fillable array as well

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'api-token',
    ];
```

and my migration has been refreshed with the changes which was adding the 'api-token' field

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps(); 
        });
```

However I still get the same error, which is:

```
null value in column "api_token" violates not-null constraint

(SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "email", "password", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Bradley, foo@bar.com, $2y$10$IBq0yEumngpeWf/oql1HgeMRYP1ANj.owXqkMc7gtIN/kxcW46Giu, 2017-05-03 13:37:56, 2017-05-03 13:37:56) returning "id")
```

The error clearly shows the `api_token`field isn't even being considered when inserting a new User. Have I missed some sort of update to Laravel that I need to do after making changes to a model in order for it to take effect?

Comment: I flag this question for closure since this is a simple typographical mistake which is unlikely to help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fillable you added `api-token` while in your migration and creation you use `api_token`.
Notice the difference between the `-` and `_`.

Comment: I feel ashamed to have not noticed this.